# If cell Value Changed Then run different If statements

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, onchange, is-empty

I'm currently trying to make a spreadsheet that can be used to input and store large volumes of data. One way of speeding up the process of inputting the data is to copy data from the previous row. So far what I have is:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$J$3" Then

Call LD_Copy_Paste_Delete

End If

End Sub

Sub FillBlanks()

If Range("B13").Value = Empty Then
    Range("B14").Selects
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

If Range("C13").Value = Empty Then
    Range("C14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("C13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

If Range("D13").Value = Empty Then
    Range("D14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("D13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


If Range("E13").Value = Empty Then
    Range("E14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("E13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("E13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


If Range("F13").Value = Empty Then
    Range("F14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("F13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If

End Sub
```

What I would like is for the FillBlanks() to run just after the first sub, without having to do anything more. All help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Why not call it at the end of first sub?

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
Call FillBlanks
```

right before the `End Sub` of `Worksheet_Change`

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cl as Range

    If Target.Address = "$J$3" Then
        Call LD_Copy_Paste_Delete
    End If

    For each cl in Range("B13:F13")
        If cl = "" Then
            cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
        End if
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What Siva states in his comment sounds correct but I would like to exemplify a few points beyond it. Indentation is important to make the code readable and understand what is happening easier. In the code below I have indented and added the update as Siva suggests, along with a number of comments to aid in the understanding of what the code does.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'When the user changes the selection to cell J3 then do the work
If Target.Address = "$J$3" Then
    'Adding a line to run fill blanks as Siva suggested
    FillBlanks
    Call LD_Copy_Paste_Delete
End If

End Sub

Sub FillBlanks()

If Range("B13").Value = Empty Then
    Range("B14").Select 'There was an extra 's' here that would never have worked
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    If Range("C13").Value = Empty Then
        Range("C14").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("C13").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("C13").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        If Range("D13").Value = Empty Then
            Range("D14").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("D13").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Range("D13").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            If Range("E13").Value = Empty Then
                Range("E14").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Range("E13").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Range("E13").Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                If Range("F13").Value = Empty Then
                    Range("F14").Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Range("F13").Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                    Range("F13").Select
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

The nested `If`s (that are clearer to see with indentation) means that for example, the F13-F14 FillBlank will only run if *all* others before were blank as well.

I'm not sure this is the best way to do this or what you may have been trying to achieve. I'd like to suggest some other options that may be of help:-

**1. Copy all if F13 is empty**

```
Sub FillBlanks()

If Range("F13")= "" Then
    Range("B14:F14").Copy Range("B13:F13")
End If

End Sub
```

**2. Copy only empty ones, regardless of surrounding ones**

```
Sub FillBlanks()

If Range("B13") = "" Then Range("B14").Copy Range("B13")
If Range("C13") = "" Then Range("C14").Copy Range("C13")
If Range("D13") = "" Then Range("D14").Copy Range("D13")
If Range("E13") = "" Then Range("E14").Copy Range("E13")
If Range("F13") = "" Then Range("F14").Copy Range("F13")

End Sub
```

In the second one I have used the feature where `End If` can be omitted if the statement to be run is a single line

This may have been a slight over code review but hopefully it has served as an education and answered the question too.